# Field count in PIG

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Is there any way to find the number of Fields or columns available in a relation?

For example:

```
a = load 'input' using PigStorage(',') as (a1,a2,a3);

b = load 'input2' using PigStorage(',') as (b1,b2,b3);

C = join a by a1, b by b1;
```

Now there will be six columns in the result 'c'. Is there any way to check the count of columns in the result by code.

Thanks,

Kalai

Comment: The best I can think of is to do `DESCRIBE C;` and count outside of Pig (i.e., manually by hand).

Answer (score 2):

PIG does not provide any intentional way of counting columns but one of the way to use the count of fields in pig is by 1st -storing the file and then counting the no of delimiters in the file.

Example:-   (Delimiter used is "|")

**%declare COUNT `hadoop fs -cat //trihadn01/user/ykale/warranty_recs | head -1| tr '|' '\n'|wc -l`;**

and then use this variable - COUNT where ever required in pig.

**Note-** Please do not miss the '`' symbol at the end of the statement and after the variable name (count)